# Regex to match a float after a particular expression

Tags: python, regex, match

I'm trying to extract, in my python script, from a long documents all the floats that follow a particular expression, that is

```
>250
```

After ">250" there are a certain number of spaces and the float can be in the form

```
12.34
```

or

```
12
```

An example is:

word word 150 175 200 225 >250 12.3 word word

and 12.3 should be matched

I managed to build a regex of the type

```
\b>250\s+\S+
```

but I do not know what to put in place of S+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
>250\s+(-?\d+\.?\d*)
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/UNbHDQ/1)

`>250` - match `>250`

`\s+` - match 1 or more number of spaces

`(-?\d+\.?\d*)` - match a int/float into a capturing group